# Token type depends on following token

Tags: java, antlr

I am stuck with a pretty simple grammar. Googling and books reading did not help. I started to use ANTLR quite recently, so probably this is a very simple question.

I am trying to write a very simple Lexer using ANTLR v3.

```
grammar TestLexer;

options {
  language = Java;
}

TEST_COMMENT
    :   '/*' WS? TEST WS? '*/'
    ;

ML_COMMENT
    :   '/*' ( options {greedy=false;} : .)* '*/' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

TEST    :   'TEST'
    ;

WS  :   (' ' | '\t' | '\n' | '\r' | '\f')+ {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;
```

The test class:

```
public class TestParserInvoker {
    private static void extractCommandsTokens(final String script) throws RecognitionException {

        final ANTLRStringStream input = new ANTLRStringStream(script);
        final Lexer lexer = new TestLexer(input);

        final TokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        Token t;
        do {
            t = lexer.nextToken();
            if (t != null) {
                System.out.println(t);
            }
        } while (t == null || t.getType() != Token.EOF);
    }


    public static void main(final String[] args) throws RecognitionException {
        final String script = "/* TEST */";
        extractCommandsTokens(script);
    }
}
```

So when test string is "/* TEST */" the lexer produces as expected two tokens. One with type **TEST_COMMENT** and one with EOF. Everything is OK.

But if test string contains one extra space in the end: "/* TEST */ " lexer produces three tokens: **ML_COMMENT**, WS and EOF.

Why does first token get ML_COMMENT type? I thought the way how token detected depends only on precedence of lexer rules in grammar. And of course it should not depend on following tokens.

Thanks for help!

P.S. I can use lexer option filter=true - token will get the correct type, but this approach requires extra work in tokens definitions. To be honest, I do not want to use this type of lexer.

Comment: +1 It took me a second to parse through that but that seems "odd".

Comment: What for do you put `WS?` another rule? With being in a hidden channel or skipped, it does would never occur in another rule.

Comment: @Kay I specified token TEST_COMMENT which can contain arbitrary number of whitespaces (WS). I do not need WS token by itself during the parsing stage.

Comment: @Kay, `WS` only gets put on the HIDDEN channel if it's a token of its own. When part of another rule, the white space chars it matches are on the channel of _that_ particular token.

Comment: and @Bart: My fault, thanks for clearing that up. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANTLR tokenizes the character stream starting from the top rule downwards *and* tries to match as much as possible. So, yes, I would also have expected a `TEST_COMMENT` to be created for both `"/* TEST */"` and `"/* TEST */ "`. You can always have a look at the generated source code of the lexer to see why it chooses to create a `ML_COMMENT` for the second input.

Whether this is a bug, or expected behavior, I would not use separate lexer rules that look so much a-like. Could you explain what you're really trying to solve here?

> ***user776872 wrote:***
>
> I can use lexer option filter=true - token will get the correct type, but this approach requires extra work in tokens definitions. To be honest, I do not want to use this type of lexer.

I don't quite understand this remark. Are you only interested in a part of the input source? In that case, `filter=true` is surely a good option. If you want to tokenize all input source, then you shouldn't use `filter=true`.

### EDIT

In case of making a distinction between multi line comments and Javadoc comments, it's best to keep these in the same rule and change the type of the token if it starts with `/**` like this:

```
grammar T;

// options

tokens {
  DOC_COMMENT;
}

// rules

COMMENT
  :  '/*' (~'*' .*)? '*/'
  |  '/**' ~'/' .* '*/' {$type=DOC_COMMENT;}
  ;
```

Note that both `.*` and `.+` are by default non-greedy in ANTLR (contrary to popular belief).

### Demo

```
grammar T;

tokens {
  DOC_COMMENT;
}

@parser::members {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TLexer lexer = new TLexer(new ANTLRStringStream("/**/ /*foo*/ /**bar*/"));
    TParser parser = new TParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));
    parser.parse();
  }
}

parse
  :  (t=. {System.out.println(tokenNames[$t.type] + " :: " + $t.text);})* EOF
  ;

COMMENT
  :  '/*' (~'*' .*)? '*/'
  |  '/**' ~'/' .* '*/' {$type=DOC_COMMENT;}
  ;

SPACE
  :  ' ' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
  ;
```

which produces:

```
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/T$ java -cp antlr-3.3.jar org.antlr.Tool T.g
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/T$ javac -cp antlr-3.3.jar *.java
bart@hades:~/Programming/ANTLR/Demos/T$ java -cp .:antlr-3.3.jar TParser 
COMMENT :: /**/
COMMENT :: /*foo*/
DOC_COMMENT :: /**bar*/
```

Comment: Thank you, Bart! I used debugger for generated Lexer class and to be honest I've lost in DFA.predict methods calls. I did not expect that I hit the bug in ANTLR so fast (I just started to use this tool) and that is why decided to ask here first.

Comment: I think my case is very similar to java doc comment and regular java comments. But I have never seen somebody mentioned this type of error.

Comment: I am working on very simple SQL parser that can extract SQL commands from script. In this case I just need to specify in parser the boundaries for each command. You are right - I need just the part of code. Firstly I used filter=true in my lexer. Later I got rid of it, because it extracts keywords from other non-keyword words. For example token CREATE : 'CREATE' can be obtained from both input "CREATE" and input "CREATExxx"

Comment: @Anton, I didn't say it was a bug for sure, but it _could_ be. _"because it extracts keywords from other non-keyword words"_ then you have to define some `Identifier` rule and put these non-keywords on the HIDDEN channel. In your  case `filter=true` is a good option.